# How to reuse existing connection in Open Session In view pattern implementation of Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, session, design-patterns, view

I am using Hibernate by implementing "Open Session in view" pattern?It opens a new connection per request. Is there any way to use the existing connection? Is my understanding correct? May be i miss something during implementation which cause opening of new connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advice: don't implement it yourself, use an existing one, like [Spring's](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html):

> Servlet 2.3 Filter that binds a
>   Hibernate Session to the thread for
>   the entire processing of the request.
>   Intended for the "Open Session in
>   View" pattern, i.e. to allow for lazy
>   loading in web views despite the
>   original transactions already being
>   completed.

Failing that, look at the source code for the above to see how Spring does it.

Comment: Thanks @skaffman, i regret for myself for not posting this question earlier.